# Add number to URL variable? (PHP)

Tags: php, navigation

I am trying to build a simple webcomic system from scratch and I am stuck on the navigation. I have a variable in the URL declaring which comic to display on the page and I need to make a "next comic" button that adds to the number in the URL to display the next comic. I cannot get this to work.

Here is the code I have for the page so far:

```
<?php $comix = 9; ?>

<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<p><img src="comix/<?php echo $_GET["id"] ; ?>.png" alt="Comic"></p>

<nav id="comicnav">
<?PHP
if ($comix > $_GET["id"]) {
echo("<a href='comic.php?id=" . $_GET["id"] +1 . "'>Next</a>");
}
else{
    echo('Next'); //Disabled link when the latest comic is reached
}
  }
?>
</nav>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: I don't see any immediate problem in that code. Can you describe what part of it doesn't work?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to xss attacks

Comment: If your ID is an int, try this: $newNum = $_GET['id']++;                echo("<a href='comic.php?id=$newNum'>Next</a>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo("<a href='comic.php?id=" . $_GET["id"] +1 . "'>Next</a>");
```

You should put ints in brackets:

```
echo("<a href='comic.php?id=" . ($_GET["id"] + 1) . "'>Next</a>");
```

I tested it, I think you got html error in first code

Comment: You are wrong. First code creates this html : "1'>Next</a>"

Comment: Second: "<a href='comic.php?id=6'>Next</a>", which is correct

Comment: I don't know, why are you repeating. Just test 2 codes on web-server. And you will see different html

Comment: lenden...can you please edit your answer? I can't remove my downvote unless (according to SO) you edit your answer....I had a long day and did not see the parentheses you added (you called them brackets...threw me off).

Comment: One moment, please :)

Comment: +1. this is totally correct: `'a' . 3 + 4 . 'b'` comes out as `4b`, and is executed as `('a3' + 4) . 'b'` -> `(0+4).'b'` -> `4b`. The `.` binds tighter than `+`.